# Range of the use of "something is off"

Tags: phrase-usage

Can "something is off" be used for objects or events as well? I have found it mostly being used to describe people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a very generic phrase meaning that something is not quite right. It often refers to a gut feeling/intuitive kind of response, and so such a generic phrase is used because the person is unsure of precisely what is “off” and so can’t be more specific.

So it can be used with people, objects, situations, etc.

As for events, I’m unsure of your meaning here, but thinking of events as being an event that has occurred (in the past), you would say “something ***was*** off”.